# Gulp error when trying to run in terminal (no syntax errors)

Tags: gulp

I`m running a tutorial from Lynda.com and i'm trying to run a gulpfile, the syntax is good but I can't understand the error from terminal.

Could anyone provide me help with this one?

Many thanks!

gulpfile.js

```
var themename = 'pistol4';

var gulp = require('gulp'),


autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
image = require(gulp - image),
jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),

//Only work with new or updated files
newer = require('gulp-newer'),

//Name of working theme folder
root = '../' + themename + '/',
scss = root + 'sass/',
js = root + 'js/',
img = root + 'images/',
languages = root + 'languages';

// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function () {
return gulp.src(scss + '(style.css,rtl.scss)')
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    indentType: 'tab',
    indentWidth: '1'
}).on('error', sass.logError))
.pipe(postcss([
    autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
    ]))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
.pipe(gulp.dest(root));
});

//Optimize images trough gulp-image
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(img + 'RAW/**/*.(jpg,JPG,png)')
    .pipe(newer(img))
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(img));
});

//Javascript 

gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src([js + '*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(js));
});

//Watch everything
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: 'pistol.dev',
        port: '8080'
    });
    gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css', root + '**/*.scss'], ['css']);
    gulp.watch(js + '**/*.js', ['javascript']);
    gulp.watch(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

//Default task (runs at initiation: gulp --verbose)
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

error log from terminal:

```
assert.js:81
throw new assert.AssertionError({
^
AssertionError: missing path
at Module.require (module.js:495:3)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\pistol01.06.17\wp-
content\themes\gulp-dev\gulpfile.js:7:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Comment: image = require(gulp - image), this line seems fishy to me.

Here you define  a var, which value is the required module which path is defined by the image var itself? 

This could be causing your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much Juan, indeed that was the problem, i deteled that line and it works fine, but after taht i encountered this one "[BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
" may i get your help once again? Many thanks!!

Comment: Great! Were you able to fix that? if not, do you happen to have this in a public public repo? If we could clone it, we could assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `image = require(gulp - image),` wont work just like @Juan said. Did you mean: `image = require('gulp-image'),`?

The next error:

> "[BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a
>   headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
>   "

Since I never worked with browser-sync, I can just guess and write stuff i found from googling it.

I have two suggestions:

1. Go into the 'watch' task and change: `browserSync.init({open: 'external',`
   to:`browserSync.init({open: 'false',` in short just do what the error said to do.
2. You need to give browser-sync the exact file you open the browser with. f.e.:  `'--browser "chrome.exe"'`

Please let us know how you fixed it or if any of this helped.